# Products showing up in subcategory when they shouldn't

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic

I have a problem where the website shows the subcategorys but also the products on the next page

[image]

just like in this image you see the sub categorys but theres a second page that shows products that has already been placed in one of the sub categorys. what irretates me is that, its only some of the products that does this and not all of them. but all products seem to have the same settings so i dont know what causes this.

Comment: note that the archive for product category A will also contain all the products in A's children and grandchildren, it's possible this is the cause of the confusion and unexpected appearances, but if not then solving this without any code will be nearly impossible, and if the answer requires knowledge of WooCommerce to write then the question can't be asked here as questions about 3rd party plugins and themes are offtopic